# Обычный get-запрос на Java

Tags: java

В `Python` есть оличная функция для `get-запросов`, с помощью которой можно получить быстро статус и контент:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print response.status_code
print response.content
```

При попытке загуглить `get запрос в Java` попадаю на разные инструкции как создать сокет, потом установить соединение и так далее. Неужели в Java нет каких-нибудь простых способов без изобретения собственных велосипедов ?

Comment: Привыкайте к тому, что код на `Java` в 10 раз больше кода на `Python`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Get`-запрос можно осуществить, например, так:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) построенный на apache http api.

```
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(uri, String.class)
.responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer()).build();

public void send(){
  ResponseHandler<String> response = httpRequest.execute(someParamsYouWant);
  System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.get()); //retuns response body
}
```