# Бот для VK на Java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, desktop

Не совсем сведущ в веб-программировании, поэтому попрошу не принимать близко к сердцу мои, возможно глупые, вопросы :)

В планах написать приложение, которое может работать с личными сообщениями (страницы ВКонтакте, или сообщества), а также с другим функционалом **VK API**.

На ruSO видел вопросы насчёт авторизации с помощью Java в ВКонтакте, но подробного описания, как с этим работать, я не нашёл.
В документации VK есть вся необходимая информация по работе с API, но там в основном JSON-запросы, *нужно иметь сервер*, который будет принимать и обрабатывать эти запросы, и так далее (https://vk.com/dev/callback_api, https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs)

Но как работать с этим с десктоп-приложения, например, со своего компьютера на Windows, я не понял.

В написании приложения у меня проблем не возникнет, но как работать с VK API и взаимодействовать с ним (отправлять сообщения, или выполнять любые другие действия) я не знаю.

Желательно, чтобы можно было:

- Хранить токены, чтобы на как можно более длительное время они хранились, и не было необходимости заново логиниться (логиниться через окошко в приложении - встроить веб-страничку не так трудно, но как заставить бота оставаться авторизованным?)
- Обрабатывать любые запросы, которые отправит VK, а также самому их отправлять (те же сообщения / любое взаимодействие)

Буду рад любым наводкам. Ещё больше буду благодарен, если приведёте пример кода, как авторизовываться и хранить эту авторизацию, как взаимодействовать с API (простейшие примеры).

Comment: Вы уже рассмотрели их [SDK для Java](https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK)? Прочитайте про [процесс получения ключа доступа](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user), такой ключ может быть постоянным, если было выдано разрешение **offline**.

Comment: У ВК есть СДК для явы https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk. А так вам надо всего лишь слать обычные сетевые запросы и всё...

Comment: Для начала надо определиться с сервером. Jetty пробовали?

Comment: @labris для работы десктоп-приложения всё равно нужен сервер? ВК не может напрямую работать с моим приложением?

Comment: Цитата: ... Далее необходимо указать и подтвердить конечный адрес сервера, куда в дальнейшем будут направлены все запросы. ...после получения уведомления Ваш сервер должен возвращать строку "ok" и статус HTTP 200. Если сервер несколько раз подряд вернет ошибку, Callback API временно перестанет отправлять на него уведомления.  - Если приложение может выполнять, к примеру, такие функции, то можно и без сервера :)

Comment: @labris тогда интересно, каким образом создать такое сообщение? Перспектива создавать сервер мне не улыбается, хотелось бы, чтобы приложение было "самодостаточным" - чтобы его можно было запустить на любом компьютере, войти через него в VK и настроить работу бота.

Comment: Вот тут практически аналогичный вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785960/creation-of-a-client-server-desktop-application

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можно ли подробнее узнать насчёт именно использования этого SDK ? Почитал сейчас то, что там на сайте, а то, как работать с ним в программе, не очень понял. Возможно, я недостаточно опытен для этого :) И ещё не ясно, тот перечень "зависимостей" (что используется) нужно самому устанавливать (apache, SLF4J), или нет? Буду благодарен (если Вы имеете опыт по работе с этим) если напишете ответ с небольшими примерами :)

Comment: @labris да, вопрос схожий, но ответ на него меня не очень удовлетворяет :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для Вашей цели почти наверняка подойдет [Java SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK) от самих VK. На странице SDK подробная документация (и, в частности, [инструкция по получению access-токена пользователя](https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK?f=7.%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Перед тем, как погружаться в работу SDK, лучше прочитать про то, [как работает API Вконтакте](https://vk.com/dev/first_guide) (это небольшая статья).

Скорее всего, вам нужно именно standalone-приложение. Для них нормально в качестве `REDIRECT_URI` использовать `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` (это даже обязательно для некоторых методов API).

Чтобы access-токен жил вечно, в `scope` добавьте значение `offline`.

---

С API без SDK взаимодействуют так:

```
// формируют url запроса
String url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get?count=20&access_token=<access_token>";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// из документации: параметры могут передаваться как методом GET, так и POST. Если вы будете передавать большие данные (больше 2 килобайт), следует использовать POST. 
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
// посылаем запрос и сохраняем ответ
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
// выведет json-ответ запроса
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

(код get-запроса взял [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579709/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java))
А далее нужно распарсить полученный `json`-ответ.

Авторизация — труднее. Там надо открыть окно браузера со сформированным `url`, задетектить редирект, распарсить `access_token` в новом `url`.

---

Хорошим упражнением будет походить по исходникам [Java SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk/blob/master) и разобраться, как реализовано там. Например, исполнение `message.get` начинается [тут](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/vk/api/sdk/actions/Messages.java#L62).

Comment: Да, я видел и Java SDK, читал про VK API, и так далее, но мне до сих пор интересен механизм работы приложения, которое взаимодействует с этим API, отправляет\обрабатывает запросы. Хотя бы, например, как авторизоваться, и вывести в консоль, например, имя аккаунта, или что-то другое. То есть, как оперировать с полученными данными, и как их отправлять.
В документации описано всё довольно подробно, но там лишь описания методов, что они делают и т.д., а конкретно про механизмы взаимодействия я не понял.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin то есть, хотите понять, как это делается без SDK?

Comment: Хочу увидеть примерный код реализации взаимодействия с API. Например, как будет выглядеть отправка сообщения в коде программы, как с этим работать. Видел, что для этого используются `https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send` и так далее, то есть не могу понять как мне сформировать в приложении этот запрос, как  его отправлять и всё такое :)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin обновил пост.

Comment: То есть мне нужно 1. Получить `access_token`, 2. Посылать сформированные запросы, 3. Парсить `json`-ответы, и, в зависимости от них, дальше действовать ? Если я получу `access_token` (валидный) и отправлю этот `messages.send` запрос, то сообщение будет отправлено, или мне нужно будет разбираться с json-ответом на запрос и что-то делать далее ещё?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin на этот вопрос отвечает [документация](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send): вам придет json-ответ, из которого вы узнаете, отправилось сообщение или нет.

Comment: Могу ли я в чате здесь (как оно тут работает..) или в личных сообщениях в ВК задать в будущем парочку вопросов по взаимодействию с API ?) Проблем с самой Java не возникнет, но вот веб и api для меня тёмный лес, пока что. Буду крайне благодарен :) Поставлю галочку ответу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55218/discussion-between-paul-vergeev-and-peter-samokhin).

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться моей библиотекой.

Для авторизации понадобится получить access token в ВК. Остальное все делается за 2 минуты. [VkApiProvider](https://github.com/JavaStream/vk_api_javastream) на github, там есть даже пример реализации.

Будут вопросы, обращайтесь.

Comment: На этом сайте ответы содержащие только ссылку на сторонний ресурс, ответом не считаются (возможно удаление). _там есть даже пример реализации_, вот как раз его и добавте внеся [правку в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1185360/edit).